# Pass Parameter Value from Datatables Button to a Function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, datatables, bootstrap-modal

I' trying to pass the value of a button in a datatables to a function. However I'm just getting the value of the first row. Hope you can help me. I just need to alert the parameter then I'll take care of the rest.

here's the code

memberlist.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; Charset="UTF-8"');
$columns = array( 
// datatable column index  => database column name
    0 => 'HoId',
    1 => 'Name',
    2 => 'ClusterName',
    3 => 'MemStatus',
    4 => 'EmailId',
    5 => 'RegDate'
);
include 'database.php';
$sql = "SELECT mi.HoId, CONCAT(mi.FirstName,' ',mi.LastName) as Name,mi.Cluster,mi.MemStatus,mi.EmailId,mi.MobileNo,mi.RegDate, ci.ClusterName, ci.CHname"; 
$sql2 = " from tblmemberinfo mi LEFT JOIN clusterinfo ci on ci.id = mi.cluster";
$sql3 = $sql.$sql2;

$res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($conn));
$dataArray = array();
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res) ) {


                 $HoId = $row['HoId'];
                 $Name = $row['Name'];
                 $ClusterName = $row['ClusterName'];
                 $MemStatus = $row['MemStatus'];
                 $EmailId = $row['EmailId'];
                 $RegDate = $row['RegDate'];
                 
                $dataArray [] =  array("HoId" => $HoId,
                                        "Name" => $Name,
                                        "ClusterName" => $ClusterName,
                                        "MemStatus" => $MemStatus,
                                        "EmailId" => $EmailId,
                                        "RegDate" => $RegDate);


}
$str = mb_convert_encoding($dataArray, "UTF-8");
echo json_encode($str);

?>
```

action.js = I just need to alert the parameter then I'll take care of the rest.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#memberlist').DataTable( {
    "ajax": {
            "type" : "POST",
            "url" : "includes/memberlist.php",
            "dataSrc": function ( jsondata ) {
                return jsondata;
                
            }       
            },
            
    "columns": [
            { "data": "HoId" },
            { "data": "Name" },
            { "data": "ClusterName" },
            { "data": "MemStatus" },
            { "data": "EmailId" },
            { "data": "RegDate" },
            {   data: null, 
                render: function(data, type, row) {
                    return '<button id="memberlist_but" type="button" value="'+ data.HoId +'"class="btn btn-block btn-primary">View</button> '
                    

                }},

        ],

    } );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't know about the **response data** for datatable, very well.
This is an example. (from https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)

```
{
   "draw":3,
   "recordsTotal":57,
   "recordsFiltered":57,
   "data":[
      [
         "Gloria",
         "Little",
         "Systems Administrator",
         "New York",
         "10th Apr 09",
         "$237,500"
      ],
      [
         "Haley",
         "Kennedy",
         "Senior Marketing Designer",
         "London",
         "18th Dec 12",
         "$313,500"
      ],
      
      ...

      [
         "Jennifer",
         "Chang",
         "Regional Director",
         "Singapore",
         "14th Nov 10",
         "$357,650"
      ]
   ]
}
```

As you can see, after you receive `jsondata` in `dataSrc` callback, the array must be found at `jsondata.data`, and also `jsondata.recordsTotal` and `jsondata.recordsFiltered` have to be initialized from server.

Additionally, please try to analyze the response data from 'really-working' server with Chrome Dev tools.

[image]

Comment: got the parameters in my datatables.. I just want to alert it to a javascript function. In Dev tool I can see all parameters I need each row so no problem with that.. Problem is I cant pass it to js function or jus alert it and I'll do the rest.. Note: I know how to use dev tools.

Comment: Sorry for that. But, you missed `jsondata.data`. Response data - `$dataArray` is only an array, that is why you got errors. Capsulate `$dataArray` to `{..., data:$dataArray, ...}`.